# Problema com matriz numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Estou com um problema usando NUMPY. Tem uma matriz `testeSolucao`, desse tipo `<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>`, e eu preciso pegar o menor valor dela, mas não consigo. Primeiro achei que fosse um vetor, mas está gerando essa matriz por conta das operações que estou fazendo. E como é uma matriz com apenas uma linha eu to tentando pegar a linha 0 dela e ir pegando os índices, mas todo retorno do `menor` eu recebo sempre `[[ 7.5   3.    0.25]]`.

```
def verificaSolucao(testeSolucao):
    indice = 0
    menor = testeSolucao[0][indice]

    for i in range(1, 3, 1):
        if testeSolucao[0][indice] < menor:
            menor = testeSolucao[0][indice]
            indice = i

    if menor<0.0:     
        return (indice)
    else:
        return (-1)
```

Comment: Achei uma solução `testeSolucao.item(i)` funciona pegando cada item

Comment: Você pode postar a sua resposta como uma resposta, não como um comentário! Depois de alguns dias vc pode aceitar ela como resposta e assim a questão fica resolvida. Se alguém tiver outra resposta, não tem problema, quanto mais melhor.

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer isso!

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução `testeSolucao.item(i)` funciona pegando cada item